# Get form field value via module [VBA]

Tags: forms, vba, module

I have a program built with VBA, in access.
I have a form with the field chDate and I need to get the value of the field in a module file named Global (not class module).

I tried to access it but I think I get empty value, string. not error.
I'm no expert with VBA, its new to me (I have experience with VBS).

Can someone please help me and tell me how can I access the value of a form field via module file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide some sample code, it might help us in trying to get you a solution.

Here's what might work:

`Dim` an object as an instance of your form, and set the instance to a new instance. These two lines will do that (assuming the form is called `frmForm`)

```
Dim theForm as frmForm
Set theForm = new frmForm
```

then Show that Form:

```
theForm.show
```

The form will get the focus, so you can populate the fields. At that point, once the form is **hidden**, your code should be able to pull the field as such:

```
var1 = theForm.txtFormField.Text
```

However, if you **unload** the form in code, all variables directly tied to the form will be lost. In that case, you might want to follow Oneide's example, and set a global variable to the value of the form field. You can do this in one of the form's event handlers.

Comment: I tried your code (my form name is lstVisits):
Public Function ShowVisitsDate() As Date
    Dim theForm As lstVisits
    Set theForm = New lstVisits
    theForm.Show
End Function

But I'm getting an error:
Compile error:
User-defined type not defined

Its on the first & second lines (on the form name: lstVisits)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can recall my Access days. In your global module you should access the form field be prefixing the form name i.e. 
var1 = Form1.txtFirmField.Text

Comment: This gives me an error: Error 424: Object Required.


I also tried to access the field value lik this:
Forms![cdform]![chDate]

And I'm getting this error:
Error 2427 "You have entered an expression thacccat has no value." 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you're trying to get the data the wrong way.

Anytime you would try to get your form data, **from a standard module**, your form probably will already be closed or, if you're not opening it as a restricted window, the value will not be ready yet.

Anyway, if you could get pass through all the difficulties above, you're probably coding in a not standard / right way.

Remember that VBA is an **event driven** language, and you would be better using it's strenghts rather than fighting against them.

As a final word, if this is just a casual coding, I suggest you using a global variable and make de *Code Behind Form* have set it up on control's change event.

If you're not sure what I mean, please leave a comment and I'll try to explain it better.

And, if you don't mind, let us know more about your starting code to get better answers.