# VBA to wait for response from UserForm and Import to table BeforeSave?

Tags: excel, wait, before-save, vba

How do I have VBA wait for response from the UserForm "SavePrompt", then depending on the selection (Ok or Cancel) have the VBA continue?

I need the user to fill out a text box before the workbook saves.

This information will be then imported to column B on Table1.
Column A is the current date and time.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("EDITS")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

    SavePrompt.Show



With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = TextBox1 'this is from the SavePrompt Userform
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That already happens. The code after `SavePrompt.Show` will only execute after the form is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get form field value via module \[VBA\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5618219/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBox1` is a property of `SavePrompt` instance, not a variable.

Instead of this:

```
With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = TextBox1 'this is from the SavePrompt Userform
End With
```

... you should write this:

```
With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text
End With
```

Comment: thanks. but the 

    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text

Is not filling out column B. What am I missing?

Comment: Just after I asked the Previous comment/Question "What am I missing?" I figured it out. I added...

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    SavePrompt.Hide

    End Sub

I forgot to do this and was trying to save using the close X in the top right corner. My appologies. Thanks for you Help!